# How will swift memory management will handle this scenario?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider:

```
class A {
    var a: Int
    var b: String
    weak var s: CustomType?

    init(a:Int, b: String, s: CustomType?) {
        …
    }

    func methods() {
    }
}

class B {
    …
    var a: A
    
    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
    } 
}

class C {
   var b: B
   init(s: CustomType?) {
       let a = A(a: Int, b: String, s: CustomType?)
       b = B(a: A)
   } 
}

// main
let s : CustomType? = CustomType() //
let c = C(s)
...
...
// finish
```

In this scenario do I need to be worried about the memory management of `s` or `class A`'s object `a`?
or Swift's memory management system (garbage collector?) will automatically take care of it ? (or `a` can become dangling ???)

Answer (score -1):

In the Swift memory management system (ARC; see below), objects are released as soon as there are no more strong references. In this case, `C` keeps strong reference to `B`, and `B` keeps strong reference to `A`, so as long as you maintain a strong reference to `C`, your instances of `A` and `B` will remain. When you remove your strong reference to C, A and B will be released, too.

But you have `s`, a `CustomType`. And neither `A`, nor `B`, nor `C` keep a strong reference to it. So if/when “main” removes its last strong reference to `s`, even if `C` (and, therefore, `A` and `B`, too) have lingering strong references, the `weak` reference to `CustomType` in `A` will be set to `nil`.

---

As a minor clarification, Swift does not use garbage collection. It uses [automatic reference counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/automaticreferencecounting) (ARC). Objects are released and deallocated as soon as the last strong reference is removed (as opposed to garbage collection, where this clean-up happens at a time at the discretion of the memory management system). The idea of `ARC` is to provide the developer a slightly more deterministic understanding of precisely when objects are deallocated.